# How to update this query with 2 data arrays for WHERE condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, sql-update

hi i have 2 data arrays ,

```
$lob_array = array(200,201,300);
$preference_array = array(500,501,502,503,504,505);
```

i have a table `rating`

it has fields

```
rating_id | lob_id | preference_id | average_rating | is_delete
```

i want to update the `is_delete` column with the values according to data array .

i want to compare each lob value with `$preference_array`

```
UPDATE 
rating SET is_delete = 1 
WHERE 
 (lob_id=$lob_array[0] AND preference_id IN (".implode(',',$preference_array).")) ) OR
 (lob_id=$lob_array[1] AND preference_id IN (".implode(',',$preference_array).")) ) OR
 (lob_id=$lob_array[0] AND preference_id IN (".implode(',',$preference_array).")) )
```

how can i do this , please help , because i don't know the number of elements in `$lob_array` thanks
in advance.

Comment: I didn't understand how you match `lob_id` to the `preference_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work?

```
UPDATE 
rating SET is_delete = 1 
WHERE 
 (lob_id IN (".implode(',',$lob array).") AND preference_id IN (".implode(',',$preference_array)."));
```